# Call external swf from an swf in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, external

I am new in Flex and I face some difficulties..

I have a swf gallery that load external swf files when you click differnet button..

I have load this swf inside Flex but when I click the buttons it doesn't load the external files..

I use this

> `<mx:SWFLoader source="@Embed(source='test2.swf')"`

I assume that maybe there are some security issues in flex where you can't loda external swf??

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing dynamic swf loading with embedding assets.

The syntax @Embed is used for embedded assets that are included in the application binary, during compilation. 
You should write:

```
<mx:SWFLoader source="test2.swf"
```

to dynamically load a swf file from the same web server than your app.